# JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration messes my Bean Constants

Tags: java, spring, httpsession

I am using spring MVC 4.2 I have this code in my app-context.xml

```
<bean id="beanConstants" name="beanConstants" class="com.my.web.controller.BeanConstants">
    <property name="dbProplocation" value="/my/database.properties" />
    <property name="extractDbProplocation" value="/my/extract.database.properties" />
    <property name="cssLocation" value="uncompiled" />
    <property name="enableSuspensionPollingStr" value="false" />
</bean>

<!--  JDBC Session Config -->
<bean class="org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration"/>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${hibernate.connection.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${hibernate.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}" />
</bean>
```

Now this all worked fine until I added the JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration bean.  If I take that line out,  it works.  otherwise I get this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.connection.url' in string value "${hibernate.connection.url}"
```

I am trying to save the sesstion info in the DB.  Why is this doing this?  What has one got to do with the other?

Comment: I don't believe that `JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration` itself is somehow related to the problem. Most probably something more general. May be there are different errors in the log console?

Comment: You `.properties` file can't be recognized so the palceholder `hibernate.connection.url` in the dataSource config can't be found. Either fix the `.properties` file detecting or try to hardcode the connection url.

Comment: @Andremoniy  I remove that one bean,  and it works.